# Benchmark Win2D in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, benchmarking, direct2d, win2d

I spent some time playing with [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) today.

I follow the instructions in the Readme.md of that page, basically just installing a NuGet package and add a few lines of code and then it starts to work, neat!

What I am really interested in is that `Win2D`, which is a C#/XAML 'wrapper' for `Direct2D`, uses "hardware acceleration" which the old plain `System.Drawing/GDI+` does not, Wikipedia page for `Direct2D` claims the performance boost is quite substantial.

So I write two functions to draw 3000 ellipses on a Win2D `CanvasControl`, and a plain `Canvas`, respectively. In my test, the time taken by `canvasControl_Draw` is less than the time taken by `Canvas_Loaded`, by some 20%-50%.

My questions are:

1. Is the benchmark setup correct? I am not even sure if I am comparing `Win2D/Direct2D` to `System.Drawing/GDI+`, or comparing something else. **I don't know if drawing on plain `Canvas` is already `Direct2D`.**
2. Is there some easy to follow benchmark setup that can clear demonstrates Win2D is much performant than, say, GDI+?

XAML

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--xmlns:canvas="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"-->
    <canvas:CanvasControl 
        ClearColor="CornflowerBlue" 
        Draw="canvasControl_Draw" />

    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" 
            x:Name="canvas" 
            Loaded="Canvas_Loaded" />   
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
private void Canvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Random r = new Random();

    var stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    {
        var ellipse = new Ellipse()
        {
            Stroke = stroke,
            StrokeThickness = 3,
            Width = r.Next(1, 200),
            Height = r.Next(1, 100)
        };
        ellipse.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, r.Next(1, 600));
        ellipse.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, r.Next(1, 800));
        canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Canvas_Loaded end at {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
}

private void canvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    {
        args.DrawingSession.DrawEllipse(r.Next(1, 600), r.Next(1, 800), r.Next(1, 200), r.Next(1, 100), Colors.Black, 3);                
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"canvasControl_Draw end at {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
}
```

Comment: According to the [Visual layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/visual-layer) page, it already *relies on graphics hardware acceleration*, i.e. XAML components are based on DirectX.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will write some _Graphics.DrawAbc_ in WinForms to see if there is something interesting.

Comment: Just draw on off-screen bitmap.